# how to get items from the option of a <datalist> in php

Tags: php, html

`$_POST` return null value in the database. Why does this happen?

```
<datalist name="countries" class="form-control">
    <option value="India">India</option>
    <option value="United States">United States</option>
    <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
    <option value="France">France</option>
</datalist>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['countries'])){
   $country=$_POST['countries']; 
}else{
    echo 'no value';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a normal form submission.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $country = $_POST['countries'];
    echo $country;
}

?>

<form method="POST">
    <input list="countries" name="countries" />
    <datalist id="countries">
        <option value="India">India</option>
        <option value="United States">United States</option>
        <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option> 
        <option value="Germany">Germany</option> 
        <option value="France">France</option> 
    </datalist>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

> Notice: This is a relatively new tag, so some browsers might not support this. I suggest just use plain `<select>` tag

Answer (score 0):

You are posting the `gender` in your code but it is undefined. Try replacing the `gender` with `countries`.

```
if (isset($_POST['countries'])){
   $gender=$_POST['countries']; 
}else{
    echo 'no value';
}
```

Comment: done but error Undefined variable: country in G:\xammp\htdocs\med\information.php

Comment: @tom030888 its `countries` not `country`

Comment: that doesnt make any sense, post method name and the datalist name should be same to identify not the declared name

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility after looking at the code might be this.

```
if (isset($_POST['countries'])){
   $gender=$_POST['countries']; 
}else{
    echo 'no value';
}
```

Comment: then the probable one will be the tag name is not correct the correct name is 

datalist and not data list No space between the word data and list

Answer (score 0):

The [Datalist](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp) tag is not supported in several browsers.It's a recent HTML5 tag. If you use a browser that does not support it, it will not send the values with the form data or the value that the user puts into the associanted input field is used like an input text tag.

Also I suppose that your component is in a form with POST method. if not exist a form or the method is GET or nothing (GET is default) the $_POST array is not filled.

Test this code. If it works instead DataList your browser probably is not capable to use DataList tag

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $country = $_POST['countries'];
    echo $country;
}

?>
<form method="POST">
    <select name="countries">
        <option value="India" />
        <option value="United States" />
        <option value="United Kingdom" />
        <option value="Germany" />
        <option value="France" />
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

I recommend to use javascript to create the suggestion box with a simple imput. For example using [JQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) making your code compatible with more browsers.

In the [Datalist](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp) W3c schools page there is a table with the support of this component. Not all browsers support it at other like IE only in last version.

- Also [Datalist](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp) requires an input component where the user places the values ([see w3cshools example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp)) and this component **name** will be the real name used by the $_POST

Example (only html, php code is the same):

```
<input name="countries" class="form-control" list="countries_list" />

<datalist id="countries_list"> 
    <option value="India">India</option> 
    <option value="United States">United States</option> 
    <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option> 
    <option value="Germany">Germany</option> 
    <option value="France">France</option> 
</datalist>
```