# How to use Ajax and the HTML structure to echo autocomplete options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, html-datalist

1. I want to create an autofill search box. it gets a JSON and sends them to an HTML5 `<datalist>` of `<option>`s.

It works fine but it cant use spaces in values! so it just returns the first word. for example, if the `jresults.name` is "lets go" - I get only "lets".

What is the best way doing this?

2. This part: `$( "#prod_name_list" ).children().remove();` prevents me of choosing an option from the list. because it deletes everything in it when I "keyup" so I need a different solution for this.
3. The second part is after submitting the form I want to get the id chosen of the object. (`jresults.id`) and I'm not sure how to retrieve it with the submit.

**MY CODE:**

JS part:

```
        $("#prod_name").bind("keyup", function(e) {

            if (e.which <= 90 && e.which >= 48){

                $( "#prod_name_list" ).children().remove();
                var prod_name = $("#prod_name").val();

                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo site_url('kas/search_prod_name'); ?>",
                    data: ({ "prod_name": prod_name }),
                    success: function (result){

                        var jresults = JSON.parse(result);
                        console.log("jresults: "+jresults);

                        var lng = jresults.length;
                        console.log("lng: "+lng);

                        for (var i=0; i<lng; i++) {
                            if (jresults.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                                  console.log("name: "+jresults[i].name);
                                  $("#prod_name_list").append("<option name=\"prod_id\" id="+jresults[i].id+">"+jresults[i].name+"</option>");
                            }
                        }

                    }
                });

            }

        });
```

HTML part(using codeigniter syntaxes for the form:

```
<?php 
    $attributes = array('class' => 'prod_name', 'id' => 'prod_name', 'name' => 'prod_name', 'list' => 'prod_name_list');


        echo form_input('prod_name',  'prod Name', $attributes);    
    ?>

    <datalist id="prod_name_list"> 


    </datalist>
```

Comment: I will suggest you to look into https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ I know that's not answer of your question. But it will help you to implement auto complete easily. And it has selected event handler. On selection you can keep id  in hidden field.  I'm using mobile phone right now and can't help you much.

Comment: I don't want to use the jQuery UI. I don't want to load unrelevant libraries to my website for only 1 thing :X

Comment: You are already using JQuery hence gave  you a suggestion.

Comment: yeah, i know, I want to gain the experience doing this from 0 with jQuery

Comment: Did you check the result json which you are getting from Server?

Comment: yes, i used the console.log twice. one here:   `console.log("name: "+jresults[i].name);` and once before converting the result json string to a real json object. I get the outputs right. I think the `value="x"` in the option tag doesn't accept spaces.

Comment: although this explains differently :S 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523899/how-to-get-items-from-the-option-of-a-datalist-in-php

Comment: Your option tag is having little problem. In the value attributes put database identity value. And your actual display text between option tag.  <option value='1'> display name</option> ps. I'm not sure if thats the exact issue

Comment: Oh, So this is the way doing this :O worked! problem 1 solved. 

Any idea how to solve the second problem with the `remove()` ?

Comment: Oh, when I select an option using the mouse it outputs an ID in the <input> :(

Comment: @RickSanchez Change `keyup` to `keypress` and use `if (e.which !== 0)` to check if there was a character pressed rather than any other key. You could also do the `.remove()` within the success function so you're sure that you're refreshing and not removing only to get an error back. I'm not sure why the remove would prevent you from selecting anything unless you're using the keyboard to select.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to work on here, but let's jump into a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/a2z7e1yb/

The **HTML** I tested with:

```
Name: <input class="prod_name" id="prod_name" name="prod_name" list="prod_name_list" />
<datalist id="prod_name_list">

</datalist>
```

The **JQuery** I would advise using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#prod_name").keyup(function() {
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "<?php echo site_url('kas/search_prod_name'); ?>",
      data: {
        "prod_name": $("#prod_name").val();
      },
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        var options = "";
        $.each(result, function(k, v) {
          console.log("name: " + v.name);
          options += "<option value='" v.name + "'>\r\n";
        });
        console.log(options);
        $("#prod_name_list").html(options);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

As was mentioned, you can use `onKeyPress` versus `onKeyUp`. I leave that up to you.

I did testing with test data that looked like:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Lets Go"
  }, {
    "name": "Go More"
  }
]
```

The `$.each()` works well for this. It will iterate over each array item and place it's Key into `k` and each object into `v`. We then generate a string of all the options and replace whatever is inside our `datalist` So if the result set is 15 options on the first character, it would be replaced ion the next keystroke with whatever result set we get.

Using `.remove()` and `.append()`, in my mind, becomes cumbersome for this type of application. You want to remove all the options, or replace them, with whatever new data you receive. In my working example, when a key is pressed, we see:

```
<datalist id="prod_name_list">
  <option value="0">Lets Go</option>
  <option value="1">Go More</option>
</datalist>
```

I hope this is clear and helps you out. If it's not, leave a comment and let me know.

**Update**

I think you may be using the `<datalist>` tag incorrectly. It should be fully populated when the page loads, not after text is entered. See more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

It should be used like so: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/a2z7e1yb/2/

```
<label>Name:
<input class="prod_name" id="prod_name" name="prod_name" list="prod_name_list" /></label>
<datalist id="prod_name_list">
  <option value="Let's Go" />
  <option value="No Go" />
  <option value="Go Back to Bed" />
</datalist>
```

If you really want to make it like JQuery UI's Autocomplete, you would build a `<ul>` or `<div>` with the results as a list inside. This list would be populated when a key is pressed, showing just the relevant results. For example if "L" was pressed it would sen that value to your PHP which would show "Let's Go" and any other product Names that begin with "L". It's different than `<datalist>` which looks for anything in your List that contains "L".

Comment: Looks almost good, I'll try it on my code a few minutes.. The problem again. witht he `keyup` or `onKeyPress` - Lets say I have 3 options after clicking, when I use the arrow down button to choose (and not use the mouse), it get "refreshed" and then I cant actually navigate down using the arrow keys.

Comment: And when I choose an option I get the ID as value and not the text. 
I almost solved the problem, see my  edited JS code.

Comment: my only problem is 1~ sending the ID number the json returns with the form. 2~ when choosing an option, so I need to insert the ID somewhere permanent because I still get all the options listed.